# How to add the RoutedEventArgs as the Command Parameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand, commandparameter

We can use ICommand instead of Routed Event to implement MVVM,
so we can write the logic in ViewModel.

Here is a example:

```
<Button Width="40" Command="{Binding CommandOne}">Click1
</Button>
```

But we need to Set CommandParameter all by ourself, 
and my problem is how to send the RoutedEventArgs as the CommandParameter.

```
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

How can I use the RoutedEventArgs as the CommandParameter in my ViewModel?
Any ideas?

Comment: why would you need RoutedEventArgs in VM? what Data you want to send with your command ?

Comment: In WebBrowser, when Navigating i need the navigating url which is in NavigatingCancelEventArgs.

Comment: Cant you just pass the navigating URL as the CommandParameter, e.g: `CommandParameter="{Binding Source, ElementName=myWebBrowser}"`

Comment: I don't want the source, I want the redirect url during the Navigating procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any straight forward way of doing this (nothing I know). But this can be achieved using interactivity `EventTrigger` and defining your own `TriggerAction` to capture the `EventArgs` and send as `CommandParameter`.

Here is one example of doing this. Here the example is of different event but can be applied to any.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/5cd586e7-640f-447b-9040-e9270173abf7/passing-drop-event-data-in-a-command-parameter-using-mvvm-and-the-interactivity-framework

Comment: Thanks, I gone using an attached behavior to doing this. When attached a command to an Routed event, give the RoutedEventArgs as parameter to this command's execute method.Maybe next time I will try the way you tell me.

Comment: I've test the method you told me, it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: you might want to post the answer in that case... implementation of attached behaviour... thanks :)